# RAD Studio долго загружается

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-berlin

Работаю на RAD Studio Berlin 10.1. Все работало отлично до сегодняшнего времени а сегодня просто началась очень длительная загрузка среды RAD Studio. Я ничего не делала, ничего не обновляла.

То есть вчера RAD Studio загружалась нормально **за 10 секунд**. **А сейчас за 7 минут** и при этом висит заставка (Прикрепила). Что посоветуете?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В порядке вероятности - 1. Обновите антивирус и проверьте систему, мб подхватили что-то; 1. Попробуйте наоборот отключить Антивирус, вдруг он лютует; 3. Проверьте HDD на исправность (мб сбоит и "сыпется"); 4. Посмотрите в Мониторе Ресурсов, чем занят CPU/HDD/RAM.

Comment: @Kromster, Уже это все проделала. Но странно то что все программы на этом диске работают и загружаются нормально и быстро а вот RAD Studio медленно загружается но вот работает быстро.

Comment: @Kromster, Я так понимаю что вся проблема в том что долго идет загрузка: Design time пакетов (как показано на рисунке). Как это исправить ?

Comment: При помощи Process Monitor https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/procmon можно увидеть все обращения к файлам и регистру. Ищите. проверьте firewall и Event Log. Возможно идет обращение к внешнему ресурсу (или к нескольким) с таймаутом несколько минут.

Comment: У меня так 10.3 в один прекрасный день, ни с того ни с сего, перестала загружаться и начала висеть на этой заставке, попутно нагружая одно ядро CPU на 100%. И никакие мои телодвижения в итоге не помогли, спасла только переустановка.

Comment: @zed У меня была аналогичная проблема. Спасло переименование  startpageide260.bpl  в *.bak (можно и стереть было). Это удалило страницу приветствия и развесило Delphi.